Logging CAN bus load over time
I have used CANKing, which displays the bus load in real-time.  However, I would like to do some long-term monitoring to see what the load looks like over time.
This site claims to have free software that will plot data, but between it being called "asammdf"  and Windows not being able to validate the executable, my suspicious software alarms are going off.
Any suggestions of a way to chart CAN bus load over time?

This really depends on the hardware you have. If it's natively supported by SocketCAN in the Linux Kernel, you can just use wireshark to record all traffic, filter it and save it.

The name "asammdf" sounds pretty good, though, to me. I'd be much more worried if it was called "Advanced Free CAN Bus logger (free)" or such.

CSS Electronics are a good brand, and asammdf (docs) is entirely open source, so feel free to ease your concerns... does it help to know that "ASAM" stands for "Association for Standardization of Automation and Measuring Systems", and "MDF" stands for "Measurement Data Format"?

"Any suggestions of a way to chart CAN bus load over time?" this is going to be difficult to do with anything above the physical layer, because any errors will take an unknown amount of time. You'll need tools that can measure this, and not just present error stats along with good frames recieved.

Kvaser do have loggers too. I've used them but I can't say that I liked them, wasn't very flexible. You'd set up some trigger condition like an error frame then have it record from there. Maybe they could start recording upon a certain bus load even - not sure. Otherwise my personal preferred brand of any CAN equipment is IXXAT so that's where I'd start looking for logger tools.
